# How to reconnect to docker instance

Tags: azure, docker, docker-machine

I'll start from the beginning.

1. I've created an Ubuntu machine with docker installed on Azure.
2. On the top I created two docker containers, I used to connect from an old computer using docker-machine for management tasks.
3. I've changed my computer, so I need to connect from the new one.
4. I've added my azure subscription

However when I try the `docker-machine` cdmdlet to the existing container I have the following error message:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker-machine ssh vm name
Host does not exist: "vm name".
```

The machine is running but I'll guess I'll have to recreate the certificates used for the connection.

I've tried the following with no luck:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker-machine regenerate-certs vm name
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): y
Regenerating TLS certificates
Host does not exist: "vm name"
```

I no longer have access to the old machine.

Has anyone been into the same situation?
Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: Are you using 'vm name' here, or just substituting for the real name of your VM?

Comment: Hi Francois
It's just to subtitute the real name of the VM, I'll guess your question it's about the space. For sure the machine name has no spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to recreate the machine using the *generic* driver:

```
docker-machine create \
  --driver generic \
  --generic-ip-address=203.0.113.81 \
  --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
  vm
```

Replace the information accordingly.

Note that this does NOT remove any data on the target instance, rather it just configures docker to talk to machine if it isn't already, and also generates new certificates so it can communicate with the instance.

Comment: Hi tcnj
Thanks for the answer!, is there another solution or how can I keep the existing data within the containers?. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This will keep your existing data. It uses SSH to connect, rotate certificates and then reconnect. The generic driver is designed to use already existing machines that may or may not have docker on already.

Comment: Hi tcnj, thanks for the clarification!. I've tried he command as suggested but I got the the following error message: Error with pre-create 
Detecting operating system of created instance...
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: OS type not recognized

Comment: I've also tried  docker-machine.exe regenerate-certs vm   But I get the same error message:
Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): y
Regenerating TLS certificates
Waiting for SSH to be available...
Detecting the provisioner...
OS type not recognized
Any ideas??

Comment: @cdanvergara That was happening to me because I wasn't specifying a user.  There's another flag for the generic driver, --generic-ssh-user <USERNAME>.  That allowed SSH to connect successfully for me after previously receiving the error about not detecting the OS type.